# How can I protect my OLED screen from burn-in?

Tags: display

Is there a utility that can prevent burn-in on OLED screens for Ubuntu 18.04? Something that automatically prevents the screen from showing the same pixel value for too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the [xdg-screensaver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-screensaver.1.html) after enabling it, or use [Xscreensaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XScreenSaver) ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xscreensaver.1.html)).  The former blanks the output, whereas the latter provides your choice of blank output, or multiple outputs which randomize the content.

Answer (score 1):

### What the experts say

From [OLED screen burn-in: What you need to know now](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/oled-screen-burn-in-what-you-need-to-know-now/):

> So if the fear of the mere possibility of burn-in is your primary
> concern, the decision is simple: buy an LCD-based display instead. But
> know that you're sacrificing the best picture quality that money can
> buy. Here are some points to keep in mind:
>
> - Burn-in is possible with OLED, but not likely with normal use.
> - Most "burn-in" is actually image retention, which goes away after a few minutes.
> - You'll almost certainly see image retention long before it becomes permanent burn-in.
> - Generally speaking, burn-in is something to be aware of, but not worry about.

---

### Some tips for Ubuntu

- Auto hide the launcher and only have it appear when the mouse bumps the window border where it is docked.
- Periodically shift the location of the application indicator panel from top to bottom and back again.
- Blank the screen after 10 minutes of inactivity. This is how the function got it's name "screen saver" in the first place.