# Can I run ASUS OLED Care in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, display, brightness

I recently bought an ASUS laptop with an OLED preinstalled with Windows 11. ASUS provides a package of tools called OLED Care that includes features like brightness dimming and a pixel shifter.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in dual boot configuration and realized that I will not have these features on Ubuntu. Now, I am worried about my OLED screen when I use ubuntu.

Are there any packages in Ubuntu which provide features similar to ASUS OLED Care?

Does this mean I cannot use Ubuntu on my OLED laptop? What precautions can I take to avoid harming my display? I prefer to use Ubuntu as I did not find WSL good enough.

Comment: Yes, I know I can still use ubuntu but just worried that It may affect my screen life. Brightness I understand, I can control but there is this pixel shift tool which says it always keeps shifting pixels on the screen a little bit invisible to the eye to prolong screen life. I wish to know if there is some alternative to that on ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I protect my OLED screen from burn-in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193065/how-can-i-protect-my-oled-screen-from-burn-in)